# zappa deployment: deploy to same api gateway with different stages

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zappa

when I define a new stage in zappa_settings.json a new api-gateway-backend gets created. What I would need is the same gateway but a different stage, ie. /prod instead of /dev.
Is there any way of accomplishing this in zappa?

Answer (score 0):

Zappa does not currently support that model.

Comment: depends on what your goals are.  if you want all stages under a single domain, then you could use a separate CloudFront distro and front all of the stages with origin urls.  if you want to conserve api gateways on your account, I don't know of a solution.

Comment: How did you solve this? Cant you let zappa create a new gateway and then manually add a new stage to the first gateway and point that to the second function?